# Python class, strange error

Tags: python, class

I have a class, nothing special, just a regular class:

```
class WINDOW ():
    def __init__ (self, path):
        ...some unrelated codd...
        self.win = newwin(stdscr.win.getmaxyx() [0]-2, stdscr.win.getmaxyx() [1], 0, 0)
        self.xmax = self.win.getmaxyx() [1]
        self.ymax = self.win.getmaxyx() [0]

    def draw(self,flin,fcol):
        ...code here
        i = 0
        while i < self.ymax -1:
            ...more code here...
```

When I try to access "self.ymax" in the while loop, I get error, saying that classs WINDOW has no atribute ymax.
What have I done wrong???

Edit:
getmaxyx() returns a tuple of two values.
This is a curses program. I'm using python 3.

Edit 2:
More code - creating an instance of WINDOW:

```
def main():
    global stdscr
    stdscr = initscr()
    global interface

    interface = INTERFACE(stdscr)
    interface.wins.append(WINDOW(parseArgv()))

    dispatcher()
```

Parseargv():

```
def parseArgv():
    #arguments are [filename, PathToFileThatThisProgramOpens]
    if len(argv) == 1:
        return None
    else:
        return argv[-1]
```

calling draw():

```
def SwitchWindow(self):
    self.wins[self.currentWindow].empty()
    self.currentWindow += 1 #select next window
    line = self.wins[self.currentWindow].flin
    coll = self.wins[self.currentWindow].fcol
    self.wins[self.currentWindow].draw(line,coll)
```

Comment: Could you try pasting your actual code? What you've pasted here isn't sufficient to tell what's happening.

Comment: Please add the code where you create an instance of WINDOW and call draw on it.

Comment: ... or at least, pls, provide exception trace

Comment: What does empty() do? Is it actually in the call to SwitchWindow that this error happens? Could you provide the exception trace?

Comment: Could be that the `self.currentWindow += 1` in `SwitchWindow` is incrementing the index past the number of Windows in `self.wins`. Without more of your code, we're all guessing. I'm going to vote to close.

Comment: Python itself never says that 'Class X' does not have an attribute afaik - either it refers to 'type object X', or 'X object'. Which is it? Can you provide the full error/stack trace as @AlexCouper asked?

Comment: I'm hesitant to close this, given the willingness to provide more info so far, but it really doesn't appear to be a question. It's virtually certain that this stems from a specific bug somewhere else in his code, and any answer is therefore never going to help anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the full code and traceback it's impossible to tell, but I have some guesses at the problem:

1. The bit replaced by `...some unrelated codd...` actually contains multiple code paths and the code we do see is only executed some of the time so `self.ymax` isn't always initialised.
2. Either `...code here` or `...more code here...` rebinds the name `self` within the `draw()` method.
3. majTheHero retyped her/his code instead of using copy and paste and in doing so inadvertently corrected a misspelling of `ymax` in one of the places it is used.

Comment: 1. was right. The constructor needs 2 arguments and in some cases only got 1. I don't understand why that isn't an exception or error, though. Thank you.